# Avg amount of items user bought over the time

Tags: mysql, sql

User has purchased many orders and each order has 1 or more items, like following:

```
order 1 > 5 items (5 rows)
order 2 > 3 items (3 rows)
order 3 > 1 item  (1 rows)
order 4 > 1 item  (1 rows)
```

How can we calculate what is user avg number of items based on 10 rows for 4 orders?

Comment: Plz share your database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select userId, count(*)/count(distinct orderNumber) avg_items
from orders
group by userId
```

Comment: Add *1.0 to one of the COUNT's, to avoid integer arithmetics.

Comment: @jarlh it's not necessary with mysql. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/51666)

Comment: @basit ignore jarlh's concern: the query will produce a floating point result as is.

Comment: Didn't know that. Just curious, how do you get integer arithmetics if that's what you want?

Comment: @jarlh use `cast(expr as signed)`. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/51668)